# open() blocks trying to open a serial port

Tags: c++, serial-port, raspberry-pi

I have simple C++ tool that runs as a daemon and will continuously read data from a serial port under Debian (In this case Raspbian, as it is running on a RaspberryPi).
The problem is that the tool apparently blocks the process when it comes to the open() statement of the code. There is no processing time visible in 'top' and it just hangs. This happens no matter which user (even root) executes it and access rights for the serial port have been checked, too. It happens on any (internal or USB) Serial Port. As soon as I once start, configure and quit minicom or screen on that port it will work.
Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong or missing here?
Here is the code up to the blocking statement, includes and comments excluded:

```
int main(void)
{
pid_t pid, sid;
pid = fork();
if (pid < 0) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if (pid > 0) {
    std::cout << "\n" << pid;
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
umask(0);
sid = setsid();
if (sid < 0) {
    /* Log the failure */
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if ((chdir("/")) < 0) {
    /* Log the failure */
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

    close(STDIN_FILENO);
close(STDOUT_FILENO);
close(STDERR_FILENO);


int tty_fd;
struct termios tio;

unsigned char c = 0;

//const char *device = "/dev/ttyUSB0";
const char *device = "/dev/ttyAMA0";

tty_fd = open(device, O_RDONLY | O_NOCTTY);  //<-- Seems to hang here!
if(tty_fd < 0){
    perror("Error opening Serial Port: ");
}
etc....
```

Thanks for all the help I can get.

Comment: Add O_NONBLOCK to the open options?  But are you sure you want the open to avoid blocking?  You can unset O_NONBLOCK later with `fcntl()` and `O_GETFL` and `O_SETFL`.

Comment: Note that when the `perror()` runs after trying to open the serial port, there is no open file descriptor for standard error, so you'll never see that message.  Usually, you keep standard error open until you've got another file descriptor available to use; then you use `dup2()` to change the meaning of standard error.

Comment: Ditto on stderr, debug your program first, then daemonize it. Better yet, add an option to toggle daemon mode.

Comment: I tried adding O_NONBLOCK to the open options resulting in the program still hanging but now using ~98% CPU and it is consuming processing time. If I add the fcntl() part after opening the program doesn't use any CPU time, just like before. In both cases a simple cout statement is not reached. (I also took the daemon part out of it.)

Comment: Verify that the usb modules have been loaded using "lsmod".  I think they are ftdi_sio and usbserial, which are loaded on demand.  I'm guessing minicom is able to trigger the load and after that your tool is able to use it.